# How to Detect that Current (Bash) Shell is a (Vi/Vim) Subshell?

Tags: bash, shell, vim

From inside Vi/Vim, I can type:

```
:shell
```

to drop into a shell.

Is there any way to detect that I am in a Vi-spawned subshell?

The environmental variable SHLVL is 2, but that does not tell me explicitly that I am in a **Vi/Vim**-spawned subshell.

On OS X, the following variables are also set: `MYVIMRC`, `VIMRUNTIME`, `VIM`.

How universal are these? Can I count on these being set in any system, if and only if I am in a Vi/Vim subshell?

If not, is there any portable, robust and hopefully efficient way to tell that I am in a Vi/Vim subshell?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see those same variables in Ubuntu 9.10 with Vim 7.2 and under Cygwin 1.7 with Vim 7.2 under Vista.

[Here is the documentation.](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/starting.html#$VIM)

Note that `MYVIMRC` may not be present if there's no `.vimrc` file.

Comment: same here on Debian Lenny, vim 7.1.  i get *SHLVL* 2 in *screen* as well (*SHLVL* 3 when in a vim-spawned subshell in one of those screen windows) so *SHLVL* itself probably isn't a good test.  perhaps *SHLVL>1* and one or more of *VIM, VIMRUNTIME, MYVIMRC*

Comment: If you find that sometimes one of those is set outside of *vim* (since they are configuration variables for *vim*), you could use `let $UNDER_VIM='Yes, probably.'` in your .vimrc and check `test -n "${UNDER_VIM:-}"` in your shell. Or if your shell has `PPID`, use *ps* to lookup the command for it and see if it looks like *vim* (could be vim, vi, rvim, evim, view, rview, etc.).

Comment: @Chris: Except that `rvim` and `rview` won't let you `:shell`.

Comment: Thanks for the info. 

Chris Johnsen -- your "let $UNDER_VIM='Yes, probably.'" idea works *perfectly*. ... THANKS!

Comment: @Chris: By the way, why are using a default to null in your test? I don't see any difference between yours and `test -n "${UNDER_VIM}`.

Comment: @Dennis: `test -n "${var:-}"` plays well with `set -u`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know OSX too well, but if it has a /proc filesystem, you can probably check the name of the parent process, like this:

```
parent=$(</proc/$PPID/exename)
if expr match $parent $(which vim) > /dev/null
then
    ...
fi
```

Comment: No /proc filesystem, I'm afraid. Though the concept could be implemented as follows:

    `if [ $(ps -o command -p $(ps -o ppid -o command -p $$ | tail -1 | awk '{print $1}') | tail -1) == vi
    then
        ...
    fi`

Pretty awkward though!

Comment: Wouldn't this be enough? : ps -o command -p $PPID

Comment: njd: it indeed would. Did not realize that `$PPID` was exported. Thanks!